# loop througt through a comma separated string in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Why this code:

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET /A i=0

FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=* delims=," %%a IN (`echo aaa,bbb,ccc`) DO (
SET /A i+=1
echo !i! %%a
)
```

gives me this output?

```
1 aaa bbb ccc
```

when instead I want this:

```
1 aaa
2 bbb
3 ccc
```

EDIT: the `echo aaa,bbb,ccc` is to simulate a command, I need to parse the output of a command

Comment: You're asking for all tokens to be assigned to `%%a` _(`tokens=*`)_, and that is what you're getting!

Comment: You probably want a plain `for` loop: `FOR %%a IN (aaa,bbb,ccc) DO (`

Comment: sorry for being not clear enough: the `echo aaa,bbb,ccc` is to simulate a command output, I need to parse the output of a command

Comment: Well you'll have to do better with your question, because as you can already see, it has been answered according to what you posted. This is a technical site, so instead of trying to simulate something, give it to us as it actually is.

Comment: @Wergio what is stopping you from defining the correct amount of tokens?

Comment: instead of `echo aaa,bbb,ccc` i need do call a custom external exe that outputs only a comma separated string as `aaa,bbb,ccc`. So I think I must use /F. thanks for your patience

Comment: @Compo thanks your edited answer is what i needed! the exe was php calling a complex script returning a comma separated string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some examples for you to peruse, *(each, IMO, progressively more robust)*:

```bsh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "i=0"
For %%G In (aaa,bbb,ccc) Do (
    Set /A i+=1
    Echo !i! %%G
)
Pause
```

```bsh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "i=0"
For %%G In (aa!a,b!bb,!ccc!) Do (
    Set /A i+=1
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For %%H In (!i!) Do Endlocal & Echo %%H %%G
)
Pause
```

```bsh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "i=0"
For %%G In ("aa|a","b&bb","!ccc!") Do (
    Set /A i+=1
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For %%H In (!i!) Do Endlocal & Echo %%H %%~G
)
Pause
```

**[Edit /]**
Based upon your poor modification and lack of supporting information, the following is all I'm currently willing to offer in return:

```bsh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "Result="
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Echo aaa,bbb,ccc') Do Set "Result=%%G"
If Not Defined Result GoTo :EOF
Set "i=0"
For %%G In (%Result%) Do (
    Set /A i+=1
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For %%H In (!i!) Do Endlocal & Echo %%H %%G
)
Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your limited information this is could fix your problem.

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET /A i=0

FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%G IN ('"echo aaa,bbb,ccc"') DO (
    SET /A i+=1
    echo !i! %%G
    SET /A i+=1
    echo !i! %%H
    SET /A i+=1
    echo !i! %%I
)
```

Comment: What's the betting that `aaa,bbb,ccc` is now something more like `aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,iii,jjj,kkk,lll,mmm,nnn,ooo,ppp,qqq,rrr,sss,ttt,uuu,vvv,www,xxx,yyy,zzz` and they don't want all of those repetetive lines? And that's before we find out about the characters each may contain!